# Python: How to perform PCA with promax rotation?

Tags: python, numpy, pca, rotational-matrices

How can I perform PCA in python, from SVD and eigenvalue decomposition with promax rotation? I've implemented a function that returns a rotation matrix [image] such that the rotated loadings are [image] and the rotated left singular vectors are [image]. How can I get the equivalent for an oblique promax rotation? A numpy-based solution would be great